# How can we use jQuery siblings() by not inside a same parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

From my below **Not working code** *[1]*, its will works fine with siblings() to disable others input field when they are have sum or amount going greater than maximum value, if all input fields are in same parent element.

For example:

```
<parent>
  <child input>
  <child input>
  <child input>
  <child input>
</parent>
```

If you try *CODE ELEMENT STEPPING* as above to below code, the code can be work.

**Not working code** *[1]*:

```js
$('.variations input').on('change input mouseup keyup', function() {

  var maxVal = 15; //Here is maximim value
  var sum = 0;

  $('.variations input').each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });

  if (sum >= maxVal) { //amount in any fields can't greater than maxVal
    $(this).siblings().not(this).prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $(this).siblings().not(this).prop('disabled', false);
  }
});

HTML:
```

```html
<div class="variations">
  <input type="number" name="sRewards" value="" class="inputReward" />
</div>
<div class="variations">
  <input type="number" name="sReward1" value="" class="inputReward" />
</div>
<div class="variations">
  <input type="number" name="sReward2" value="" class="inputReward" />
</div>
<div class="variations">
  <input type="number" name="sReward3" value="" class="inputReward" />
</div>
```

So I want to know how can we use jQuery siblings() to do stuff with others child element.

For real situation I might call many steps by using a lot of table elements:

https://jsfiddle.net/L01uexv1/1/

I will be more happy if someone suggest me on my real situation code too.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have to use the `.parent()` function and find all 'input' elements of the siblings, then just disable them, using `.prop()` function.

```js
$('.variations input').on('change', function() {

  var maxVal = 15; //Here is maximim value
  var sum = 0;

  $('.variations input').each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });

  if (sum >= maxVal) {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('input').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('input').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="variations">
  <input type="number" name="sRewards" value="" class="inputReward" />
</div>
<div class="variations">
  <input type="number" name="sReward1" value="" class="inputReward" />
</div>
<div class="variations">
  <input type="number" name="sReward2" value="" class="inputReward" />
</div>
<div class="variations">
  <input type="number" name="sReward3" value="" class="inputReward" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply and explanation! Really glad to know :) you're real Kind user!